# Error importing NPM module to nativescript app

Tags: npm, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Trying to import `@nimiq/core` or `@nimiq/core-web` or `https://cdn.nimiq.com/nimiq.js` to my Nativescript app but I can't found the way.

I've already tried with `nativescript-nodeify` but it thows and error in nativescript-vue (which I'm using)

```
Error is: Cannot find module '[...]\platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\app\tns_modules\nativescript-nodeify\patch-npm-packages.js'.
```

Comment: I haven't tried the plugin personally with Vue, but looks like there is an [open issue](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-nodeify/issues/53) for Vue support.

Comment: did you `rm -rf platforms`? Sometimes it helps.

Comment: Any luck solving this error?

Comment: @bks Is not possible due to Node specific modules